# How can I make a diferrence between 2 class model with the same name in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have two modules. Each of them have the same model class name. In the Module file I load the model:

```
  $this->setImport(array(
            'cars.models.*',
            'cars.components.*',
            'application.modules.mymodel.models.*',
            'application.modules.myanothermodel.models.*',
        ));
    }
```

In my case the mymodel and myanothermodel have a class with the same name (**MyClass**) but different functionalities. So when i called it in my **cars** module in controller:

```
$mymodel = MyClass::model()->find('month = :month and year = :year and user_id = :user', array('month' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'user' => $user->id));
```

As result it will always take the model from `application.modules.myanothermodel.models`. Is is possible to make somehow a diferrence between them ?

Comment: Is there any hope for me ? I don't want to change one of the class name, because I have to change the entire project if you understand. thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. And even in pure PHP. Use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for that

```
namespace models\mymodel\models;

class MyClass {}
```

---

```
namespace models\myanothermodel\models;

class MyClass {}
```

---

```
class AnotherClass {
    $classA = new \models\myanothermodel\models\MyClass();

/* or */

use \models\myanothermodel\models\MyClass;

class AnotherClass {
    $classA = new MyClass();
```

Also you have to import class that you use (manually calling `require` or using [`autoloading`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php))

Comment: I don't get this part why two times models here :namespace models\mymodel\models;

Comment: I am getting this :Class 'mynamespace\modules\MyClass\models\ActiveRecord' not found in

Comment: @JozsefNaghi Each class will have it's own namespace (usually namespace is same as directory tree). Also, you have to `use ActiveRecord` and any other class from another namespace (default namespace is `/`).

Comment: it is a lot of stuff for me.  I read about it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace. And it is told a little bit in another way. No use of autoloading or require setting some kind of alias, I don't know a lot of stuff.  is there any other possibilities? I appreaciate your help

Comment: @JozsefNaghi than don't use class with same name.